# Recreating a specific Edit Text Effect in WunderList in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I recently downloaded an app from the market called WunderList and it has this neat effect on a Edit Text for transparency

[image: Device Image]

I am trying to recreating the same effect for one of my applications but I am not really getting anywhere. I initially thought it is just transparency but I was wrong. Now I have put  an image with shadow as the EditText's BG an trying to set it's alpha. I am not sure If I am on the right path. I would appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: Is there any other detail that anyone would want me to add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this done through a custom 9patch image. Here's a sample result.

[image]

It's not close but I am getting closer.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually the way we do it.

We use a 9patch PNG with transparency.